# Cannot add a Primary Key to AS400 table because of foreign key that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a table on an IBMi/System-i/iSeries/AS400 that has no foreign keys, primary keys or constraints of any kind.  I am attempting to add a primary key using SQL:

`ALTER TABLE MYLIB.TBLGB ADD CONSTRAINT MYLIB.R_MYLIB_PK_GB PRIMARY KEY (GBAPP, GBTSK, GBSET, GBSTP)`

Which results in:

`Error: [SQL0538] The FOREIGN key in constraint R_MYLIB_PK_GB in MYLIB not same as the parent key. Cause . . . . . :   The FOREIGN key in constraint R_MYLIB_PK_GB in MYLIB is not the same as the parent key of table *N in *N. The FOREIGN key must have the same number of columns as the parent key and the data type and attributes of the FOREIGN key must be identical to the data type and attributes of the corresponding column of the parent key. Recovery  . . . :   Correct the statement so that the description of the FOREIGN key conforms to that of the parent key of the specified table.`

I'm totally baffled by this because there is definitely no foreign key linked to this table.  In fact, I have removed all constraints from all tables in this library.  What can I look at to determine what is blocking this?

One additional interesting detail is that this has worked fine on other, essentially identical libraries...

Comment: Might be helpful to know if this was defined as a DDL table (through `CREATE TABLE`), or a DDS table (specific file format).  Since you can specify all sorts of things in DDS files that the optimizer doesn't really appreciate.

Comment: @X-Zero That's an interesting question.  It was created using DDL on another system, but saved and restored into QTEMP and then moved into the target library.

Comment: Any chance you can share the table in a *SAVF?

Comment: Turns out that if I remove all the constraints from the tables on the system where the SAV was done, and then restore things, it all works... I'm not sure what this means though

Comment: I know it's been a long time... just curious, though (assuming you still want to pursue this) - What is revealed if you do: SELECT * FROM SYSCST WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME= 'R_MYLIB_PK_GB'

Comment: No real help, and an even longer time later, but I'm seeing the same symptom when trying to add a foreign key. The column definitions are identical between the two tables, but I get the message above, implying they're not 

I might try a RCLDBXREF, as user2338816 suggests, below.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file description and database relations with the [DSPFD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fdspfd.htm) and [DSPDBR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fdspdbr.htm) commands.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are qualified by the schema. So unless you also have a schema called mylib, remove the qualification.

The reason that it is complaining about a table, is probably because it tries to find a table in the schema, systables, but that is pure conjecture.

Comment: MYLIB is the library name (treated as Schema).  These statements do not work without the library specified, as they will default to your user library (as far as I can tell0

Comment: (in fact, MYLIB is not really the library name, I've had to obfuscate the details a bit)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the sequence of save and restore was incorrect. The table had attributes that shouldn't have been saved and should have been removed before saving. The restore has resulted in a database catalog on the new system with inconsistent elements.

If not, then the next likelihood (and just about the only other possibility) is that the database catalog had inconsistencies already before the restore was done. Those could have been introduced by improper shutdowns or other actions.

First step should be:

```
RCLDBXREF OPTION(*CHECK)
```

If problems are reported, run:

```
RCLDBXREF OPTION(*FIX)
```

If the system is too old for the RCLDBXREF command, use:

```
RCLSTG SELECT(*DBXREF)
```

No "*CHECK" option is available for the older version.

Depending on size and complexity of your database, number of resynchronizations needed and general performance characteristics of your server, either of those can run from 10 minutes to a few hours. Most unexplained database catalog problems (other than those needing PTFs) can be cleared by either of those.

The RCLDBXREF command is usually preferred, but some problems will require the RCLSTG alternative. Significant restrictions exist for RCLSTG, so be sure to read the command [Help].